# How remove invalid or specific files from fileupload in prime ng p-fileUpload?

Tags: html, angular, file-upload, primeng

I have used file upload for uploading files and I want to validate the files when I select one of them and remove it if that is not a valid file.

.html

```
<p-fileUpload #fileUpload  name="datafiles"
           [accept]=FileExtentionValue
           [url]="FileUploadUrl"
           [showUploadButton]="isUploadEnable"
           [disabled]="diableFileupload"
            (onUpload)="onUpload($event)"
            (onSelect)="validateFile($event)"
           multiple="multiple">
          </p-fileUpload>
```

.ts

```
onUpload(event) {
        for (let file of event.files) {
          this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
        }
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'info', summary: 'File Uploaded', detail: '' });
      }
```

validate filles name

```
     validateFile(event) {
    let tempFiles: any = [];
    var FileNmaeMust: any;
    for (let file of event.files) {
      tempFiles.push(file.name);
    }
    for (let i = 0; i < tempFiles.length; i++) {
      let count = 1;
      for (let j = 0; j < this.ClientDataFileTypeValue.length; j++) {
        FileNmaeMust = "";
        if (this.ClientDataFileTypeValue[j] == "Order") {
          FileNmaeMust = this.MPID + "_ORDER_";
        }
        /*** Validate File  */
        var templen = FileNmaeMust + "YYYYMMDD.psv";
        if (tempFiles[i].includes((FileNmaeMust).toLocaleUpperCase()) && tempFiles[i].length == templen.length) {
          this.isUploadEnable = true;
          break;
        }
        if (count == this.ClientDataFileTypeValue.length) {
          this.isUploadEnable = false;
          this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Files', detail: 'Please select correct file ' + tempFiles[i] });
        }
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I haved soved it using id .I have defined **#fileUpload**  and pass it to **(onSelect)="validateFile($event,fileUpload)"** function to validate and remove this file from array.

```
<p-fileUpload #fileUpload name="datafiles" 
[accept]=FileExtentionValu
[url]="FileUploadUrl" 
[disabled]="isDiableFileupload"
[showUploadButton]="isUploadEnable"
(onSelect)="validateFile($event,fileUpload)" (onBeforeUpload)="onBeforeSend($event)"
(onUpload)="onUpload($event)"
 multiple="multiple">
</p-fileUpload>
```

.ts

```
import {FileUpload } from 'primeng/primeng';

validateFile(event, uploader: FileUpload) {
        let tempFiles: any = [];
        var FileNmaeMust: any;
        for (let file of event.files) {
          tempFiles.push(file.name);
        }
        for (let i = 0; i < tempFiles.length; i++) {
          let count = 1;
          for (let j = 0; j < this.ClientDataFileTypeValue.length; j++) {
            FileNmaeMust = "";
            if (this.ClientDataFileTypeValue[j] == "Order") {
              FileNmaeMust = this.MPID + "_ORDER_";
            }
            /*** Validate File  */
            var templen = FileNmaeMust + "YYYYMMDD.psv";
            if (tempFiles[i].includes((FileNmaeMust).toLocaleUpperCase()) && tempFiles[i].length == templen.length) {
              this.isUploadEnable = true;
              break;
            }
            if (count == this.ClientDataFileTypeValue.length) {
              this.isUploadEnable = false;
              uploader.remove(event, i);
              this.isUploadEnable = true;
              this.messageService.add({ severity: 'error', summary: 'Files', detail: 'Please select correct file ' + tempFiles[i] });
            }
            count++;
          }
        }
      }
```

Comment: I have modified this code for my purposes of validating the file name to ensure that the filename is acceptable for sharepoint and other Microsoft storage technologies. While I have the validation code being hit and ready to go, I am having issues with the uploader.remove method. For some reason this will work at times and not at others, if I have files already uploaed to my database that show up in the uploader, they will sometimes show up in uploader.Files and sometimes they will not. When they don't, everything works fine. Is anyone else having this issue?

Comment: I found a fix to my issue above, if you are having that same issue, use clear instead of remove.

Comment: Hi,  @dmoore1181 I used remove for remove only specific file from array.

Answer (score 0):

***`onSelect` Event*** - Callback to invoke when files are selected.

[Official Documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/fileupload)

***Example:***

```
    <p-fileUpload #fileUpload  name="datafiles"
           [accept]=FileExtentionValue
           [url]="FileUploadUrl"
           [showUploadButton]="isUploadEnable"
           (onUpload)="onUpload($event)" multiple="multiple"
           (onSelect)="onSelect($event)">
    </p-fileUpload>

    onUpload(event) {
        for (let file of event.files) {
          this.uploadedFiles.push(file);
        }
        this.messageService.add({ severity: 'info', summary: 'File Uploaded', detail: '' });
    }

   onSelect(event) {
       // event.originalEvent: Original browser event. 
       // event.files: List of selected files.

       // Your validation code against list of selected files / selected file.
    }
```

Hope this helps.,

Comment: I did file validation but not able to remove perticular file

Comment: what is the issue? You can look at [How to remove element from array](https://www.hostingadvice.com/how-to/javascript-remove-element-array/). You have to remove files from `this.uploadedFiles` array.